# Packages (gstreamer, etc.) cause Broken Cache

Tags: 12.04, apt, package-management, cache

When installing "[Teamviewerx64](http://www.teamviewer.com/en/download/index.aspx?os=linux)", a package error occurs. Output of the error:

Title: Package operation failed

In a nutshell: The installation or removal of a software package failed.

Details:

```
installArchives() failed: (Reading database ... 
(Reading database ... 5%
(Reading database ... 10%
(Reading database ... 15%
(Reading database ... 20%
(Reading database ... 25%
(Reading database ... 30%
(Reading database ... 35%
(Reading database ... 40%
(Reading database ... 45%
(Reading database ... 50%
(Reading database ... 55%
(Reading database ... 60%
(Reading database ... 65%
(Reading database ... 70%
(Reading database ... 75%
(Reading database ... 80%
(Reading database ... 85%
(Reading database ... 90%
(Reading database ... 95%
(Reading database ... 100%
(Reading database ... 206917 files and directories currently installed.)
Unpacking libjack-jackd2-0:i386 (from .../libjack-jackd2-0_1.9.8~dfsg.1-1ubuntu1_i386.deb) ...
dpkg: error processing /var/cache/apt/archives/libjack-jackd2-0_1.9.8~dfsg.1-1ubuntu1_i386.deb (--unpack):
 './usr/share/doc/libjack-jackd2-0/changelog.Debian.gz' is different from the same file on the system
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
dpkg-deb: error: subprocess paste was killed by signal (Broken pipe)
Selecting previously unselected package gstreamer0.10-plugins-good:i386.
Unpacking gstreamer0.10-plugins-good:i386 (from .../gstreamer0.10-plugins-good_0.10.31-1ubuntu1_i386.deb) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libasound2-plugins:i386.
Unpacking libasound2-plugins:i386 (from .../libasound2-plugins_1.0.25-1ubuntu1_i386.deb) ...
Selecting previously unselected package ia32-libs-multiarch:i386.
Unpacking ia32-libs-multiarch:i386 (from .../ia32-libs-multiarch_20090808ubuntu36_i386.deb) ...
Selecting previously unselected package ia32-libs.
Unpacking ia32-libs (from .../ia32-libs_20090808ubuntu36_amd64.deb) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/libjack-jackd2-0_1.9.8~dfsg.1-1ubuntu1_i386.deb
Error in function: 
SystemError: E:Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
Setting up libasound2-plugins:i386 (1.0.25-1ubuntu1) ...
Setting up gstreamer0.10-plugins-good:i386 (0.10.31-1ubuntu1) ...
Setting up ia32-libs-multiarch:i386 (20090808ubuntu36) ...
Setting up ia32-libs (20090808ubuntu36) ...
Processing triggers for libc-bin ...
ldconfig deferred processing now taking place
```

Running `sudo apt-get -f install` does nothing. The only way to get rid of this error is to run `sudo apt-get remove ia32-libs ia32-libs-multiarch:i386 gstreamer0.10-plugins-good:i386 libasound2-plugins:i386`

What is wrong, and how can I fix this?

Thank you!

Comment: Try "dpkg --configure -a".

Comment: if "dpkg --configure -a" not work, then open /var/cache/apt and clean the "archive" and "update" folder if present. Delete any "lock" file if present.

Comment: Install "BleachBit". Run it as Sudo.

Answer (score 0):

You experience a bug in the libjack-jackd2-0 package, version 1.9.8~dfsg.2-1precise1 (which isn't a version ever published in Ubuntu, must have come from somewhere else).

It claims to be Multi-Arch: same, but that file differs between architectures.

You can certainly safely delete /usr/share/doc/libjack-jackd2-0/changelog.Debian.gz.
Then run APT again and everything run smoothly.